# Check if signed In user has ordered something in magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status, user

how do I check the user order status is completed in a custom module?

Comment: Where do you want to see it ? And how do you want to display it ?

In admin there is already a grid for selected customer in Customer > All customers > Edit on the selected customer > Orders

Comment: i want to show it on the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it easly using customer id (you can get it using instance customer session) for example.
First of all you will need to add **Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory** to your class constructor argument (automatic di) and then just use filters for the collection instace to filter by customer id and order status (all needed data saves in one table **sales_order**) Example:

```
namespace JohnnySk\SalesCheck\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\{
    CollectionFactory,
    Collection
};
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Check extends AbstractHelper 
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param CollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Collection of completed orders by customer id
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return Collection
     */    
    public function getCompletedOrdersByCustomerId($customerId)
    {
        $orderCollectionInstance = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Order::STATE_COMPLETE);

        return $orderCollectionInstance;
    }
}
```

Here I provided example of custom helper class which you can use anywhere in code of your custom module. Helper's method getCompletedOrdersByCustomerId will provide a collection for you, which you also can use as you need, if current customer (which id you will provide as a param for current method) has a completed orders - you will have items in collection, if not - you will not have items (you can check using **getSize** method)

Comment: it is returning an empty array.

Comment: How you provides $customerId value to that method and how you check result of getCompletedOrdersByCustomerId method?

Comment: yeah it is working now.